# Centrally Managed WSUS, but Updates come from Internet

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, wsus

When looking at the [common WSUS deployment options](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708628%28WS.10%29.aspx), I don't see an option where the updates are centrally managed for multiple WSUS servers, but both servers download the updates from Microsoft.

Is this a deployment option?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can in WSUS 3, your replica server needs to be configured to store updates locally.

An option will be available to store updates locally, download files from Microsoft Update, but do not download from the upstream server. Mentioned [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708431%28WS.10%29.aspx) screenshot below:

[image: Update Files and Languages dialogue]

Comment: Well, *that* would be nice to have illustrated in the deployment and storage docs.

Comment: Good find - this doesn't seem to be anywhere in the documentation, I guess I should have taken a look at my server before answering!

Comment: especially nice that the deployment guide details the following for Internally Synchronized WSUS [the upstream server] 'is the only server that downloads updates from Microsoft Update' - lies! :)

Comment: ..and that "In replica mode, an upstream WSUS server shares **updates**, approval status, and computer groups with downstream servers."

Comment: Looks like it got added to WSUS 3.0 deployment guide as "community content" but no such thing was added to the SP2 docs, at least as far as I can see.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708431%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: The above dialog can be found by browsing in the left-hand tree in Update Services - expand the server name, and look for Options in the subtree.

Answer (score 1):

I know that there are 3rd party tools that will do this type of thing for you. We use N-Able's N-Central to do it, but it'd probably be a bit pricey for what you desire and is really specific to our industry.